# Javascript Validación que no hace nada

Tags: javascript, validación, test

estoy haciendo una validación de un campo de texto con javascript pero no pasa nada.

```
<form action="cliente_ingresado.php" method="post" >
<div>
    <label for="identificacion" >Identificación:  </label> &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="identificacion" id="identificacion" required="required"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="nombre" >Nombre: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="required"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="direccion">Dirección: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="telefono">Teléfono: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="correo">Correo: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="email" id="correo" name="correo"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="sexo">Sexo: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="sexo" name="sexo"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="estado_civil">Estado Civil:  </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="estado_civil" name="estado_civil"/>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validarFormulario()">Guardar</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;


    <button type="button">Limpiar</button>
</div>
```

La validación de nombre no hace nada

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validarFormulario(){


        var txtIdentificacion = document.getElementById('identificacion').value;
        if(isNaN(txtIdentificacion)) {
            alert ("Identificación debe ser un número");
            return false;
        }

      var txtNombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
      var texto = /([A-Z\s\\]+)/i;
      if(texto.test(txtNombre)){
        alert ("Nombre debe ser texto");
         return false;            
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: esa expresión regular es para que solo te deje ingresar texto?

Comment: sí... la tengo que poner entre comillas? esa no sirve?

Comment: En realidad si hace  la validación y el post tienes que cambiar el tipo de botón submit o colocar el event.preventdefault que evita la propagación del submit

Answer (score 0):

Te comento con este ejemplo como debería ser tu **regex** para que reconozca solo letras

```js
var filtro= /^[a-zA-Z]*$/
      if (filtro.test("dfsdfd")){
      console.log("exito puras letras")
      }
      else{
      console.log("No es texto")
      }
```

---

```js
var filtro= /^[a-zA-Z]*$/
      if (filtro.test(123)){
      console.log("exito puras letras")
      }
      else{
      console.log("No es texto")
      }
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Para el caso de tu formulario pudieras acomodarlo de este modo

```html
<form action="cliente_ingresado.php" method="post">
<div>
    <label for="identificacion" >Identificación:  </label> &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="identificacion" id="identificacion" required="required"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="nombre" >Nombre: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="required"/>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <button type="button" onclick="validarFormulario()" name="submit" >Guardar</button>
</div>

  <script>
    function validarFormulario(){


        var txtIdentificacion = document.getElementById('identificacion').value;
        if(isNaN(txtIdentificacion)) {
            alert ("Identificación debe ser un número");
            return false;
        }
         
      var txt = document.querySelector("#nombre").value
      var filtro= /^[a-zA-Z]*$/
      if (filtro.test(txt)){
      console.log("exito puras letras")
      }
      else{
      console.log("No es texto")
      return false;
      }
    }
    </script>
```

> Al final y meramente opcional yo quitaría el atributo required, pues
>   si el navegador lo reconoce, este mismo interfiere con la
>   funcionalidad del código javascript que estas tratando de escribir en
>   JavaScript

Comment: Lo puse así y funciona  [code]var txt = document.querySelector("#nombre").value;
              var filtro= /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
              if (!filtro.test(txt)){               
                  alert("No es texto");
                  return false;
              }  [/code]      sin embargo envía el formulario en el caso de que no sea texto... yo deseo que se quede

Comment: @JhonHernández fijate en la actualización solo le agregué un return false y con eso debería bastar

Comment: Esto no [tomaría en cuenta letras con tildes y ñ's](https://regex101.com/r/Fp2Tuy/2/). Me siento ofendido ya que mi apellido contiene una :P

Comment: Cuando uso echo para el formulario ya no me funciona... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172048/php-validaci%C3%B3n-no-hace-nada