# Php validación no hace nada

Tags: php, validación

Hola estoy poniendo un formulario con echo, ahí hay una validación con JavaScript, pero esta no funciona.

```
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){     
            echo "<div align='center'>";    
            echo "<form action='cliente_actualizar_datos.php' method='post' onsubmit='return validarFormulario()''>";

            echo "<label for='identificacion'>Identificación </label> &nbsp;";      
            echo "<input type='text' name='identificacion' value='". $fila['identificacion'] . "'><br>";

            echo "<label for='nombre'>Nombre </label> &nbsp;";      
            echo "<input type='text' name='nombre' value='". $fila['nombre'] . "'><br>";

            echo "<label for='direccion'>Dirección </label> &nbsp;";        
            echo "<input type='text' name='direccion' value='". $fila['direccion'] . "'><br>";

            echo "<label for='telefono'>Teléfono </label> &nbsp;";      
            echo "<input type='text' name='telefono' value='". $fila['telefono'] . "'><br>";

            echo "<label for='correo'>Correo </label> &nbsp;";  
            echo "<input type='text' name='correo' value='". $fila['correo'] . "'><br>";                

            echo "<label id='label1' name='sexoLabel'>Sexo </label> &nbsp"; 
            if($fila['sexo'] == 'M'){
                echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='M' class='textoBlanco' checked> Masculino &nbsp";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='F' class='textoBlanco'> Femenino<br><br>";
            }else{
                echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='M' class='textoBlanco' > Masculino &nbsp";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='sexo' value='F' class='textoBlanco' checked> Femenino<br><br>";
            }                               

            echo "<label for='estado_civil'>Estado Civil </label> &nbsp;";  
            echo "<input type='text' name='estado_civil' value='". $fila['estado_civil'] . "'><br>";

            echo "<div class='button'>";
            echo "<button type='submit' name='submit' value='actualizar'>Actualizar</button>";  
             //<button type="submit" name="submit">Guardar</button>     
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</form>"; 
            echo "</div>";  
        }
    }

mysqli_close($conexion);

    ?>  
    <br>
    <a href="cliente.php">Volver al listado de clientes</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validarFormulario(){


        var txtIdentificacion = document.getElementById('identificacion').value;
        if(isNaN(txtIdentificacion)) {
            alert ("Identificación debe ser un número");
            return false;
        }

          var txtNombre = document.querySelector("#nombre").value;
          //var filtro= /^[a-zA-Z]\s*$/;
          var filtro =/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/g;
          if (!filtro.test(txtNombre)){               
              alert("Nombre debe ser texto");
              return false;
          }              

          var txtEstadoCivil = document.querySelector("#estado_civil").value;
          //var filtro= /^[a-zA-Z]\s*$/;
          var filtro =/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/g;
          if (!filtro.test(txtEstadoCivil)){               
              alert("Estado civil debe ser texto");
              return false;
          }              
    }
    </script>
```

No sé que pasa... en otro formulario que no usa echo funciona bien

Comment: Pareces tener un error de sintaxis en tu codigo. Justo en esta parte onsubmit='return validarFormulario()'' tienes al final dos comillas simples, deberia ser solo una, la de cierre...pero tienes dos. intenta quitarle la ultima a ver si te funciona.

Answer (score 1):

tienes un error de sintaxis en esta linea:

```
        echo "<form action='cliente_actualizar_datos.php' method='post' onsubmit='return validarFormulario()''>";
```

colocas al final del llamado a la función unas comillas simples, cuando deberia ser solo la de cierre. Ejemplo:

```
       echo "<form action='cliente_actualizar_datos.php' method='post' onsubmit='return validarFormulario()'>";
```

Intenta asi a ver si soluciona el problema.

Comment: echo "<form action='cliente_actualizar_datos.php' method='post' onsubmit='return validarFormulario()'>"; no... sigue sin hacer nada

Answer (score 1):

Javascript trabaja con id y yo tenía name... al agregar los ids funciona

```
id='identificacion'
```